# How to view unrecognizable response in SSMS from analysis server

Tags: ssms

I received the following message in ssms:

> Executing the query ... The server sent an unrecognizable response.
> The 'Member' start tag on line 1 position 4292344 does not match the
> end tag of 'Me'. Line 1, position 4292599.
>
> Run complete

But I don't understand what it means. So I want to look at this "unrecognizable response" and see what is on position 4292344 and 4292599. But how do I see the response text in SSMS?

Or does anyone know what error is causing this message?

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't view the full response text. But I think what happened was the end tag is supposed to spell `Member`, but the transmission of data was somehow cut off after `Me`, and that's what causes the error message.